# Using multiple rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm trying to create multiple rewrite rules to make friendly URL but what i did, makes my website throw error 500.

I've tried this but can't seem to make it work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&userid=$3 [L]
```

What i need is basically to make this urls work:
`domain.com/GetAnnouncements` as `domain.com/index.php?category=GetAnnouncements`
`domain.com/Persona/GetAchievements/2` as `domain.com/index.php?category=Persona&subcategory=GetAchievements&userid=2`
and there also should be third option that works 'in between' without 3rd parameter which is `&userid=2`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. You need to put conditions before rewrite rules, it's 500 internal error since it's a infinite loop. Mention all conditions(on which URL what condition should be applied) so that we could try to help you more, cheers 

Comment: i'm not sure what conditions do you mean, all i want to achieve is to redirect domain.com/categoryname to index.php?category=categoryname and if there is a subcategory, it should add it and so on

Comment: What I meant by conditions is: For example URL `http://localhost:80/Singh123` should be handled by your rules `index.php?category=$1` etc etc. So please do let us know links example and I could help you in same, cheers.

Comment: example links:
https://api.szalik.dev/?category=GetAnnouncements
https://api.szalik.dev/?category=Persona&subcategory=GetAchievements&userid=2

1st link should work as well under /GetAnnouncements
2nd link should work as well under /Persona/GetAchievements/2
there is also a option in between, without 3rd parameter which is userid

Comment: Thanks for letting know, please do add them into question to make it more clear. In comments full urls are not there, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more googling and consulting with my friend we came to this solution which works:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&userid=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you everyone who tried to help!

Comment: You just changed the order of rules. But as I mentioned in my answer this will catch everything means not only URLs which needed by you. It will catch anything since you are using `.*` so please be careful here, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file.

Make sure to use either 1st OR 2nd solution only at a time.

***Please make sure:***

- To keep your .htaccess rules file, index.php file in your root location.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

***1st solution:*** Generic rules where using regex.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(/d+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&userid=$3 [L]
```

---

---

***OR 2nd solution:*** Using specific string/URLs only as per your shown samples.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(GetAnnouncements)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(Persona)/(GetAchievements/)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(Persona)/(GetAchievements/)(/d+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2&userid=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't work, throws error 500 as well.

Comment: @szalik.dev, I have added lot of other details in my answer kindly do check them once and let me know how it goes.